# Loop a ruby hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I need to loop for a hash like this one:

```
h{ "identifier"=> ["1", "2"], "name" =>["name1", name2"] }
```

this hash is posted from a form and I should upate the record with identifier "1" whith the name "name1".

So how should I loop for this hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
params[:h][:identifier].each_with_index{|key,value|
  @person=Person.find(key).update(name: params[:h][:name][value] )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# for assigning "name1"  in place of "1"
h["identifier"][0] = h["name"][0]

# for assigning "name2" in place of "2"
 h["identifier"][1] = h["name"][1]
```

Comment: thanks for responding but what i really need is to use this hash to update an active record model as follow 'Person.find(h["identifier"][1]).update(name: h["name"][1])' but inside a loop

Comment: Try turning your identifier into symbol, that will work. else share your actual active record code.